# 404 Not found en petición AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

Pues estoy usando Spring MVC y cuando realizo la petición AJAX me da como resultado un 404. El controlador lo tengo definido así:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/mensaje")
public class MensajeController {

    public MensajeController() {
        super();
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/prueba", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String prueba(@RequestParam("cuerpo") final String cuerpo) {
        String b = null;

        String a = null;

        return b;
    }
}
```

Y la llamada ajax así:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {      
        $("#save").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var myEditor = document.querySelector('#editor');
            var html = myEditor.children[0].innerHTML;

            $.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    url : "/Gestion-Practicas/mensaje/prueba",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    data: {'cuerpo': html},
                    async: false,
                    cache: false,
                    delay: 15,
                    success: function(data){
                        alert('success');
                    },
                    error: function (xhr) {
                        alert(xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });     
        });

    });
</script>
```

Como digo, básicamente no me llega a entrar en el controlador y no sé por qué. ¿Se me está pasando algo?

**EDIT:**

La url desde la que realizo la petición es:

```
http://localhost:8080/Gestion-Practicas/mensaje/create.do
```

Y la url que me aparece en la consola de Chrome al realizar la petición es:

```
http://localhost:8080/Gestion-Practicas/mensaje/prueba
```

**EDIT2:**

Si hago una petición GET, obtengo el mismo 404, aunque la url cambia:

```
http://localhost:8080/Gestion-Practicas/mensaje/prueba?cuerpo=%3Cp%3Eaaa%3C%2Fp%3E&_=1541174604550
```

Comment: Explora la consola y fíjate la url del recurso que estas soltando en tu petición Ajax, luego de eso veras que seguramente tienes una parte equivocada en la url.

Comment: @jorge ya me fijé en eso anteriormente y la url parece estar bien 'http://localhost:8080/Gestion-Practicas/mensaje/prueba', también he probado quitando "Gestion-Practicas" pero obtengo el mismo resultado

Comment: Por favor pon la url actual de tu pagina para poder la que aparece en el navegador..

Comment: @denifersantiagofernandez he editado el post con la información

Comment: Probaste poniendo esta url en la petición? "/mensaje/prueba"

Comment: @denifersantiagofernandez sí, lo he comentado arriba, obtuve el mismo resultado

Comment: Solo como prueba utiliza esta:" http://localhost:8080/mensaje/prueba"

Comment: @denifersantiagofernandez mismo resultado poniendo la url completa en la petición ajax

Comment: Estuve leyendo en internet, por favor prueba con GET y pon el responsebody debajo de requestmapping, recuerda cambia el requestmethod en tu metodo y ajax.

Comment: ¿Gestion-Practicas es tu nombre de proyecto?

Comment: @denifersantiagofernandez he editado el post con lo obtenido con 'GET'. Y sí, ese es el nombre de mi proyecto

Comment: Bueno trata quitando los requetmapping y poniendo en la url los nombre de la clase y funcion...

Comment: El fichero que tienes es `prueba.do` o `prueba`? Lo veo escrito diferente segun donde miró

Answer (score 0):

Usas MVC? porque si es así con esta url : "/Gestion-Practicas/mensaje/prueba",

lo que hace el ajax es buscar una función en el controlador llamado prueba, por ejemplo:

```js
public function prueba()
    {
        echo 'Hola';
    }
```

PD: yo uso ajax con php, no sé en que lenguaje estas trabajando

Comment: Es un framework de Java, Spring. Y claro, en el controlador esta definido tal que así, que es como debería funcionar

Comment: Revisa este link que trata de usar spring, jquery y ajax, quizás le sirva: [Spring,Jquery,Ajax](http://www.programacionj2ee.com/spring-jquery-y-ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

La url que armas en la peticion debe ser asi:

```
url : "mensaje/prueba",
```

Comment: También lo he probado así pero la url resultante es la misma, dándome el mismo resultado

Answer (score 0):

El parámetro que declaras en tu controlador @RequestParam("cuerpo") le tienes que añadir a la url:

(...)

url : "/Gestion-Practicas/mensaje/prueba?**cuerpo="+html**,

(...)